# How do I install Wordpress from tar.gz?

Tags: wordpress

So I have wordpress-3.8.1.tar.gz whch I want to install (I know it's older version). I extract this file and ./configure says: bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

So how do I install this wordpress version from tar.gz? It should be simple but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress is PHP, you don't compile it, you just untar it and run, see the instructions:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress

You are ready for Step #2 on that page.

Comment: Alright, but on a side note, when I just do apt-get install wordpress, does it just run all those steps automatically?

Comment: Yes, that's all automatic.